# How to Make a Slider Witty like javascript?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, wt

I have started a project that Web pages serving from C++ application.

there is a lot of javascript tutorial from beginners to to novice.
and how can i embed this javascript slider to web page made by Witty C++?
i Have one server made by Qt run on Windows, one windows client made by Qt and one android client made by Qt, now i am started to web client with Witty and Qt.

But i need to only witty and Javascript Tutorial make slider.

[Javascript Tutorial](http://apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/trusty/universe/i386/witty-examples/3.3.0-1build1/file/usr/lib/Wt/examples/javascript/Popup.C)

But this link only show pop up message.

there is no basic or any example for slider. Can any anybody show how it is made?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok my error is setTimeout function in javascript. there is no fail with witty, this slider is great me , now going on styling wow:)

```
WImage* img = new WImage(root());

img->setId("imgslider");
std::string command = std::string(      "var i = 1;" 
                                          "var path = new Array();" 
                                          "path[0] = \"1.jpg\";" 
                                          "path[1] = \"2.jpg\";" 
                                          "path[2] = \"3.jpg\";" 
"var ifr = document.getElementById('imgslider');"
"function start(counter){" 
                                          "if(counter < 10){" 
                                            "setTimeout(function(){" 
                                              "counter++;" 
                                              "counter = counter % 3;" 
                                              "ifr.src = path[counter];" 
                                              "console.log(counter);" 
                                              "console.log(path[counter]);" 
                                              "console.log(ifr.src);" 
                                              "start(counter);" 
                                            "}, 1000);" 
                                          "}" 
                                        "}" 
                                        "start(1);" 
                                        );
img->doJavaScript(command);
```